# changing text of rule in antlr4 using setText

Tags: parsing, grammar, antlr4

I want to change every entry in csv file to 'BlahBlah'
For that I have antlr grammar as

```
grammar CSV;

file : hdr row* row1;
hdr : row;

row :  field (',' value1=field)* '\r'? '\n'; // '\r' is optional at the end of a row of CSV file ..

row1 :  field (',' field)* '\r'? '\n'?;

field 
      :  TEXT
    {
        $setText("BlahBlah");
    }
      |  STRING 
      | 
      ;
TEXT : ~[,\n\r"]+ ;
STRING : '"' ('""' | ~'"')* '"' ;
```

But when I run this on antlr4

```
error(63): CSV.g4:13:3: unknown attribute reference setText in $setText
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

why is setText not supported in antlr4 and is there any other alternative to replace text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

Given the following grammar (derived from original CSV.g4 sample and grammar attempt of OP (cf. question)):

```
grammar CSVBlindText;

@header {
import java.util.*;
}

/** Derived from rule "file : hdr row+ ;" */
file
locals [int i=0]
     : hdr ( rows+=row[$hdr.text.split(",")] {$i++;} )+
       {
       System.out.println($i+" rows");
       for (RowContext r : $rows) {
           System.out.println("row token interval: "+r.getSourceInterval());
       }
       }
     ;

hdr : row[null] {System.out.println("header: '"+$text.trim()+"'");} ;

/** Derived from rule "row : field (',' field)* '\r'? '\n' ;" */
row[String[] columns] returns [Map<String,String> values]
locals [int col=0]
@init {
    $values = new HashMap<String,String>();
}
@after {
    if ($values!=null && $values.size()>0) {
        System.out.println("values = "+$values);
    }
}
// rule row cont'd...
    :   field
        {
        if ($columns!=null) {
            $values.put($columns[$col++].trim(), $field.text.trim());
        }
        }
        (   ',' field
            {
            if ($columns!=null) {
                $values.put($columns[$col++].trim(), $field.text.trim());
            }
            }
        )* '\r'? '\n'
    ;

field
    : TEXT
    | STRING
    |
    ;

TEXT : ~[',\n\r"]+ {setText( "BlahBlah" );} ;
STRING : '"' ('""'|~'"')* '"' ; // quote-quote is an escaped quote
```

One has:

```
$> antlr4 -no-listener CSVBlindText.g4
$> grep setText CSVBlindText*java
CSVBlindTextLexer.java:         setText( "BlahBlah" );
```

Compiling it works flawlessly:

```
$> javac CSVBlindText*.java
```

Testdata (the users.csv file just renamed):

```
$> cat blinded_by_grammar.csv 
User,  Name,    Dept
parrt, Terence, 101
tombu, Tom,     020
bke, Kevin,     008
```

Yields in test:

```
$> grun CSVBlindText file blinded_by_grammar.csv 
header: 'BlahBlah,BlahBlah,BlahBlah'
values = {BlahBlah=BlahBlah}
values = {BlahBlah=BlahBlah}
values = {BlahBlah=BlahBlah}
3 rows
row token interval: 6..11
row token interval: 12..17
row token interval: 18..23
```

So it looks as if the `setText()` should be injected before the semicolon of a production and not between alternatives (wild guessing here ;-)

**Previous iterations** below:

Just guessing, as I 1) have no working antlr4 available currently and 2) did not write ANTLR4 grammars for quite some time now - maybe without the Dollar ($) ?

```
grammar CSV;

file : hdr row* row1;
hdr : row;

row :  field (',' value1=field)* '\r'? '\n'; // '\r' is optional at the end of a row of CSV file ..

row1 :  field (',' field)* '\r'? '\n'?;

field 
      :  TEXT
    {
        setText("BlahBlah");
    }
      |  STRING 
      | 
      ;
TEXT : ~[,\n\r"]+ ;
STRING : '"' ('""' | ~'"')* '"' ;
```

**Update**: Now that an antlr 4.5.2 (at least via `brew`) instead of a 4.5.3 is available, I digged into that and answering some comment below from OP: the `setText()` will be generated in lexer java module if the grammar is well defined. Unfortunately debugging `antlr4` grammars for a dilettant like me is ... but nevertheless very nice language construction kit IMO.

Sample session:

```
$> antlr4 -no-listener CSV.g4 
$> grep setText CSVLexer.java 
            setText( String.valueOf(getText().charAt(1)) );
```

The grammar used:
(hacked up from example code retrieved via:

`curl -O http://media.pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/code/tpantlr2-code.tgz` )

```
grammar CSV;

@header {
import java.util.*;
}

/** Derived from rule "file : hdr row+ ;" */
file
locals [int i=0]
     : hdr ( rows+=row[$hdr.text.split(",")] {$i++;} )+
       {
       System.out.println($i+" rows");
       for (RowContext r : $rows) {
           System.out.println("row token interval: "+r.getSourceInterval());
       }
       }
     ;

hdr : row[null] {System.out.println("header: '"+$text.trim()+"'");} ;

/** Derived from rule "row : field (',' field)* '\r'? '\n' ;" */
row[String[] columns] returns [Map<String,String> values]
locals [int col=0]
@init {
    $values = new HashMap<String,String>();
}
@after {
    if ($values!=null && $values.size()>0) {
        System.out.println("values = "+$values);
    }
}
// rule row cont'd...
    :   field
        {
        if ($columns!=null) {
            $values.put($columns[$col++].trim(), $field.text.trim());
        }
        }
        (   ',' field
            {
            if ($columns!=null) {
                $values.put($columns[$col++].trim(), $field.text.trim());
            }
            }
        )* '\r'? '\n'
    ;

field
    : TEXT
    | STRING
    | CHAR
    |
    ;

TEXT : ~[',\n\r"]+ ;
STRING : '"' ('""'|~'"')* '"' ; // quote-quote is an escaped quote

/** Convert 3-char 'x' input sequence to string x */
CHAR:   '\'' . '\'' {setText( String.valueOf(getText().charAt(1)) );} ;
```

Compiling works:

```
$> javac CSV*.java
```

Now test with a matching weird csv file:

```
a,b
"y",'4'
```

As:

```
$> grun CSV file foo.csv
line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'a'
line 1:2 no viable alternative at input 'b'
header: 'a,b'
values = {a="y", b=4}
1 rows
row token interval: 4..7
```

So in conclusion, I suggest to rework the logic of the grammar (I presume inserting "BlahBlahBlah" was not essential but a mere debugging hack).

And citing http://www.antlr.org/support.html :

ANTLR Discussions

```
Please do not start discussions at stackoverflow. They have asked us to 
steer discussions (i.e., non-questions/answers) away from Stackoverflow; we 
have a discussion forum at Google specifically for that:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/antlr-discussion

We can discuss ANTLR project features, direction, and generally argue about 
whatever we want at the google discussion forum.
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: no .. that didn't work and is acceptable because Java doesn't have a 'macro' facility and  Antlr provides a series of symbols like $ to recognize this type of methods.

Comment: and I think this fits best as a comment rather than an answer .. but thanks for making me think about the reason behind putting $

Comment: Hm, in the definitive antlr 4 reference section 10.3 "Recognizing Languages Whose Keywords aren't Fixed" on page 189 in my PDF eBook the actions/Keywords.g4 grammar uses this setText() as so: CHAR: '\'' . '\'' {setText( String. ValueOf(getText().charAt(1)) );} ; to convert single quoted characters into an unadorned one cjaracter string. I will try that when the environment is available again like so: antlr4 -no-listener Keywords.g4 && javac Keywords*.java - and isn't this a LEXER vs. PARSER section thing?

Comment: : Thank you so much for the pointers .. but still the issue is not resolved and the error that 'setText isn't recognized' persists . I haven't imported any java libraries . Do you have any idea what libraries have to be imported(incase some libraries have to be imported for setText)

Comment: @Percy123: Please re-check my answer. It is not in libraries, it is in the grammar to token/java transformation of antlr where the setText needs to become generated. HTH

Answer (score 2):

Couple of problems here:

First, have to identify the receiver of the `setText` method. Probably want

```
field  :  TEXT    { $TEXT.setText("BlahBlah"); }
       |  STRING 
       ;
```

Second is that `setText` is not defined in the `Token` class.

Typically, create your own token class extending `CommonToken` and corresponding token factory class.  Set the `TokenLableType` (in the options block) to your token class name. The `setText` method in `CommonToken` will then be visible.

Comment: Since CommonToken it is a concrete class extending the interface WritableToken , why should I not use the object of CommonToken class to set the text?

Comment: No fundamental reason preventing manual casting. Although, if the use is one of many, far easier and maintainable to go with the custom token. Also, if you need other methods, quite convenient to embed them in the custom token class.